# How to create issues in Redmine with Perl

Tags: json, perl, request, redmine

I'm using the code below to create issues on Redmine, but it doesn't work

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

$key='f4t3y2f4t3y2f4t23yfy4';

my $uri = 'http://localhost/redmine/issues/new';

my $json = '{
  "issue": {
  "project_id": 1,     // my project has different number.
  "subject": "Example111",
  "priority_id": 4,
  "commit": "Create"
 }
}';

my $req = HTTP::Request->new( 'POST', $uri );

$req->header( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'X-Redmine-API-Key' =>  $key);

$req->content( $json );

 print Dumper $ua->request($req);
```

The code was not creating issues in redmine, but now this code is working perfectly.

This code is correct!!!

Greetz: @HåkonHægland

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Did you enable API access and Jsonp support via Admin | Settings | API

Comment: Yes. I enable JSON and REST.

Comment: @HåkonHægland my code just execute, but not get message response.

Comment: @fernandohenrique Did you call `$ua->request($req)` to execute the request?

Comment: @HåkonHægland, yes but not work.
I review my code  and not understad the error.

Comment: What is the return value from `$ua->request($req)` ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland missed to call: print Dumper $ua->request($req);

Thanks a lot for the help.